# Creating an unstoppable service in android

Tags: android, android-service

I want to create a unstoppable service, i.e if the user clicks the Force Stop from settings->Manage Applications->APP_NAME, I want to know that any method for killing that service like `onDestroy()` is called or the android OS kills that service on its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting a service [on boot](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) with a [Sticky flag](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY) is the normal way of doing this.

Comment: Thank you very much.. It worked for me... But when the user clicks force stop the event can not be captured... so that is being a difficult task.

Comment: Its a bit nonsensical for an application to capture is own kill. That's the point of kill not to be handled by the application but just to be cleaned up by the OS. According to the documentation the service will be restarted by the system.